# Conditional probability times conditional probability

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am not sure if the Bayes rule can be used under the following conditions, can anyone help me to determine if the equation is right?
$$
P(A\mid B) \cdot P(B\mid C) = P(A,B\mid C)
$$
$$
P(y\mid A, B) \cdot P(A\mid C) = P(y, A\mid B,C)
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: do you have a proof that the second one is correct?

Comment: Sorry---I misread the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
and
$$
P(B\mid C)=\frac{P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}
$$
and
$$
P(A,B\mid C)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}
$$
The product of the first two is equal to the third precisely when
$$
\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
which says $P(A\mid B,C)=P(A\mid B)$

Comment: thanks. Could you also help me to show the second equation?

Comment: @jamesfoo: I am still looking at it, but I don't seem to be as convinced it is correct as Michael is (yet).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I Agree with you. I thought only when the first one is right,  the second could be right.